# Retrieving option set from CRM without SDK

Tags: ssis, dynamics-crm-2011, integration

I am writing an SSIS package that reads XML files and loads the data from the XML files into the CRM 2011 database. As it stands, the package reads the title of a client record, compares it to the hard-coded values in my script, and if there is a match, the value of the title option set is assigned.

However, my client wishes to now have the option set expandable. This would require the SSIS package to retrieve the entire option set from CRM, to compare the current possible values with the value in the record. But the SSIS does not use the Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk assembly - the package uses condition expressions and invokes the CRM API to get and set entities.

So I cannot use a RetrieveAttributeRequest (the normal way when using the Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk assembly) to retrieve the option set. Is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this information by looking at the SQL view "FilteredStringMap". You need to know the entity name, attribute name and also which language code you want to look at.

This is supported by Microsoft as it is using a filtered view.

Comment: This seems to be on the right track - but I'm still having some issues. I tried accessing the titles in SQL using the following statement:

    select * from FilteredStringMap
    where AttributeName = 'thr_salutation'

However, I'm only getting some of the results back. We initially had 5 values (Mr, Mrs, Ms Miss and Other), and the list has been expanded to include others (Sir, Master, Professor etc.). However these new values don't appear, even though they do in CRM.

Comment: Disregard that - I published the picklist changes, but you will need to publish all for them to appear against the entities in the FilteredStringMap view. Thanks!

Comment: I suppose the next question is - isthere any way to execute SQL through the CRM web service?

Comment: Correct you need to publish changes before the values are put into this table. As for the SQL question, You can't execute SQL through the CRM web service but if you are trying to get CRM data you can just use QUeryExpression or FetchXML. If it is external data you are after then you will have to setup a separate web service

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to get an option set list from a query expression or fetch xml. That's why I have this issue - I've been using condition and filter expressions to get entities so far, but I want to return an entire option set list to determine if a value exists.